# How to format date by using NSDateFormatter

Tags: iphone

I added a date picker to view. But when I select any date from the picker, it's shown this format:

```
Wednesday, December 14, 2011 1:50:52 PM India Standard Time
```

I want to change this format to

```
Wed, Dec 14 2011 1:50 PM
```

How can I get this format with `NSDateFormatter`?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try with below code .it will help you

```
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormat setDateFormat:@"EEE, MMM dd yyyy hh:mm a"];//Wed, Dec 14 2011 1:50 PM
    NSString *str_date = [dateFormat stringFromDate:[NSDate date]];
    NSLog(@"str_date = %@",str_date);
```

Comment: If possible, use the date and time formatting styles like `NSDateFormatterMediumStyle` since this particular format only makes sense in the US. The styles format according to the locale preferences (i. e. according to the style the user has chosen in Settings.app).

Comment: You should definitely listen to DarkDust. US-style dates are plain annoying if you are outside of the us. The (almost) rest of the world doesn't want the month before the day ;-) If you need specific parts of a date (e.g. weekday, day and month) which can't be accomplished with a date formatter style you can use the awesome `dateFormatFromTemplate:options:locale:` method. Pass it the date parts you want and it will give you a date format that is useful in the current locale.

Comment: In general hard coded date formats should be used for internal stuff only (like exporting to files, importing from websites, and communicating with APIs). Every date that goes into a UI* element should be created with a locale aware format.

Comment: I given answer as per question requirement only..i know it will create some problem if locale change.